# Showing that the coordinate mapping is one-to-one and onto.

Tags: linear-algebra

Let $V$ be a vector space and $B=\{b_{1},\dots,b_{n}\}$ be a basis.

---

1. Show that the coordinate mapping is one-to-one.

My approach:

Suppose $[u]_{B}=[w]_{B}$. Then by definition of a coordinate vector, 
$\begin{bmatrix} u_{1} \\ \vdots \\ u_{n}\end{bmatrix}=\begin{bmatrix} w_{1} \\ \vdots \\ w_{n}\end{bmatrix}$, and we see that $u_{1}=w_{1},u_{2}=w_{2},\dots,u_{n}=w_{n}$, so $u=w$, and the mapping $x\mapsto[x]_{B}$ is one-to-one.

---

2. Show that the coordinate mapping is onto $\mathbb{R}^n$.

My approach:

I'm actually stucked on this one, and I could use some hints. What i've tried so far is in letting $u=y$ so that $[u]_{B}=[y]_{B}=\begin{bmatrix}y_{1} \\ \vdots \\ y_{n} \end{bmatrix}=y$ but this looks rather circular.

Regardless, I think the first one works, any hints for the second one? Thanks.

Comment: What does it mean for a set of vectors to be a basis? How can you apply this definition to surjectivity?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That $B=\{b_1,\dotsc,b_n\}$ is a basis for $V$ means

- $B$ *spans* $V$ so for every $v\in V$ there exist $\lambda_1,\dotsc,\lambda_n\in\Bbb R$ such that $v=\lambda_1b_1+\dotsb+\lambda_nb_n$
- $B$ is *linearly independent* so $\lambda_1b_1+\dotsb+\lambda_nb_n=\vec 0$ if and only if $\lambda_1=\dotsb=\lambda_n=0$

We immediately have the following proposition

**Proposition.** If 
$$
\alpha_1b_1+\dotsb+\alpha_nb_n=\beta_1b_1+\dotsb+\beta_nb_n
$$
then $\alpha_j=\beta_j$ for $j=1,\dotsc,n$.

Can you prove the proposition?

Now, our linear map $T:V\to\Bbb R^n$ is given by
$$
T(v)=\langle \lambda_1,\dotsc,\lambda_n\rangle
$$
where $v=\lambda_1b_1+\dotsb+\lambda_nb_n$. This map is well-defined by the fact that $B$ spans $V$ and the above proposition.

To show that $T$ is one-to-one can you prove that $\ker T=\{\vec 0\}$?

To show that $T$ is onto, let $\langle \lambda_1,\dotsc,\lambda_n\rangle\in\Bbb R^n$. Then let 
$$
v=\lambda_1b_1+\dotsb+\lambda_nb_n
$$
What is $T(v)$?